# Function overwrites object value with value from nested array

Tags: javascript

If there is a value in the original object with 's' in it, it gets overidden by the value inside the array, that is nested in that object.

Where is the error.

**final result** (after function call):

```
{
  value: 's2', 
  test: [
    { value:'s2' }, 
    {}
  ]
}
```

**expected output**:

```
{
  value: 's1',
  test: [
    { value:'s2' }, 
    {}
  ]
}
```

```js
const sobj = {}
const simplify = (con, sobj) => {
  Object.keys(con).forEach(key => {

    let value = con[key];
    if (typeof value === "string" && value.includes('s')) {
      sobj[key] = value;
    } else if (Array.isArray(value)) {
      value.forEach((p, i) => {
        sobj[key] = sobj[key] || [];
        sobj[key][i] = {}
        simplify(p, sobj[key][i]);
      });
    }

  });
}

const data = {
  value: 's1',
  test: [{
      value: 's2',
    },
    {
      value: 'test'
    }
  ]
}

simplify(data, sobj)

console.log({ data, sobj });
```

Comment: Can I know what the objective of the code is?

Comment: what is the expected output? what are you getting?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: the expected output is {value: 's1', test: [{value:'s2'}, {}]}, but it is coming as {value: 's2', test: [{value:'s2'}, {}]}

Comment: What is the input? ```simplify(data, sobj);``` ??

Comment: const data = {
  value: "s1",
  test: [
    {
      value: "s2",
    },
    {
      value: "test",
    },
  ],
}; const sobj = {};

Comment: There are four semicolons missing and the first arrow function needs brackets arround its param "key": ```forEach((key) =>```

Comment: @decpk i rolled back your edit because it changed the original code of the question (i don't mean reformatting). If you want to talk about it, here is the [chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232581/changing-code-in-a-question) i opened for this...

Comment: Switching to an interactive snippet, seems to show that your code functions as intended, the change of `sobj.value` to `s2` doesn't appear to happen here and implies it's elsewhere in your code.